# Invulnerable and Untouchable

Tags: league-of-legends

Is it possible for a Maokai to become completely invulnerable with a fully stacked Leviathan while he's inside of his ultimate? The Leviathan blocks 15% of all damage, and the Ultimate blocks 20%. This is a whopping 35% and then there's all of his Armor and Magic Resist. With about 185 Armor and MR you get 65% then the Leviathan and Ultimate you get another 35% making it 100%... On top of masteries, such as the mastery that reduces the damage you take by a flat 3 (trust me, it really helps)..

If this happens, would the only way to damage Maokai be to use Armor and Magic Resist reducing methods and Penetration as well as True damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short no.  Not sure if there is a hard limit to damage reduction (like Cooldown reduction cannot exceed 40%), but damage reduction is based on a soft reset where they multiply, not add together.  We'd first look at the effective armor/MR that the champ may have and look at the damage that is incoming.

Let's say you have 100 armor effective after all the armor pen, and they are doing physical damage of 100.  This would mean you take 50% less physical damage.  So their 100 damage would now do 50 damage to you.  If you are in Maokai's ultimate, this is further reduced by 20%.  20% of 50 is 10, so it blocks 10 more damage.  You would take 40 damage instead.  If you have Leviathan fully stacked you take 15% less - that would be 40*.15 = 6 damage less or you take 34 damage now.  If you are Poppy and were to die to this 34 damage incoming, you reduce that by another 50% and you now take 17 damage.

So effectively you end up reducing 83% of the damage that you would have taken.  This is with reduction of 50% from armor, 20% from Maokai's ult, 15% from Leviathan, 50% from Poppy passive.  Or we could just multiply how much you would take from each together: 0.5 * 0.8 * 0.85 * 0.5 = 0.17